# Full Access to HDD Without Removal

Tags: windows, usb, firewire

I work on-the-side doing computer repair. Standard operating procedure is to pop out the HDD/SSD, mount it to a backup machine, and pull the client's data (i.e., in case the drive fails/something goes horribly wrong, their data is protected). More and more often, my office is seeing SSDs soldered directly to the motherboard, making this technique impossible.

I was wondering if any of you knew of a some method that would allow direct disk access without drive removal. An analogue would be mounting a phone in Mass Storage Device mode, I suppose. This may be possible already by doing something with a Linux LiveUSB, but I'm not sure how. Booting from a LiveUSB and transferring files over the network is unacceptably slow given the volume of computers we see and amount of data involved.

On Apple computers, this is simple--plug in a Thunderbolt/Firewire connector and use Target Disk Mode to pull directly from the drive.

tl;dr: making a backup of a Windows computer without opening them: how do?

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live Linux from a *large* USB3 HDD, and use the same disk to copy the client's data to with about USB3 speed.